# OroPlatform: attachmentExtension is null

Tags: php, symfony, orocrm, orocommerce

So I should add Image attribute to oro_brand, so I followed https://doc.oroinc.com/bundles/platform/AttachmentBundle/attachment-bundle-config/#use-migration-extension-example.

When I use `bin/console oro:migration:load --force -vvv`

I get :

```
Process migrations...
  > Oro\Bundle\EntityExtendBundle\Migration\LoadEntityConfigStateMigration
  > Test\Bundle\BrandBundle\Migrations\Schema\TestBrandBundleInstaller

In AddLogoToBrand.php line 42:
                                                           
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
  Call to a member function addImageRelation() on null
```

`$this->attachmentExtension` seems null. But I don't know why, It's look like the documentation and the vendor usage I found.

Here my code

```
//src/Test/Bundle/BrandBundle/Migrations/Schema/v1_0/AddLogoToBrand.php

use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Oro\Bundle\AttachmentBundle\Migration\Extension\AttachmentExtensionAwareInterface;
use Oro\Bundle\AttachmentBundle\Migration\Extension\AttachmentExtensionAwareTrait;
use Oro\Bundle\EntityExtendBundle\EntityConfig\ExtendScope;
use Oro\Bundle\MigrationBundle\Migration\Migration;
use Oro\Bundle\MigrationBundle\Migration\OrderedMigrationInterface;
use Oro\Bundle\MigrationBundle\Migration\QueryBag;

class AddLogoToBrand implements Migration, OrderedMigrationInterface, AttachmentExtensionAwareInterface
{
    use AttachmentExtensionAwareTrait;

    public const LOGO_SIZE = 10;
    public const BRAND_TABLE = 'oro_brand';
    public const FIELD_NAME = 'logo';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getOrder(): int
    {
        return 10;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function up(Schema $schema, QueryBag $queries): void
    {
        $this->addLogoBrandAssociation($schema);
    }

    /**
     * @param Schema $schema
     */
    public function addLogoBrandAssociation(Schema $schema)
    {
        $this->attachmentExtension->addImageRelation(
            $schema,
            self::BRAND_TABLE,
            self::FIELD_NAME,
            [
                'extend' => ['owner' => ExtendScope::OWNER_CUSTOM]
            ],
        );
    }
```

SOLVED :

I removed my `TestBrandBundleInstaller` and it is working now.

Comment: Make sure the migration namespace is correct, and it matches the directory structure.

Comment: The namespace working